# Where to find ClearDB MySQL database in the Full Azure Portal?

Tags: mysql, azure

I have created a MySQL database (backed by ClearDB) in the Preview Azure portal (portal.azure.com) but I cannot see it anywhere in the full portal (manage.windowsazure.com).

Where can I find it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will show as a 'Linked Resource' on the main Dashboard page for your Website. This will then provide you with a 'Manage' link which will open up ClearDB's management portal.