# How to find ClearDB MySQL database in Azure portal?

Tags: mysql, azure, cleardb

I am logged into my Azure portal and I can see the "app service" dashboard and "resource group" dashboard for my web app, but I cannot find the ClearDB MySQL database that the web app uses.

I don't see the "linked resources" anywhere as mentioned in this question:

[Where to find ClearDB MySQL database in the Full Azure Portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815376/where-to-find-cleardb-mysql-database-in-the-full-azure-portal)

To clarify, I am using ClearDB and not "MySQL in app".

Answer (score 0):

> How to find ClearDB MySQL database in Azure portal?

According to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170024-additional-services/suggestions/6814490-drop-cleardb-and-develop-a-native-azure-mysql-comp), we could know that ClearDb is dropped. And I also can't find it from the Azure Market.

There is a native Azure MySQL compatible database - [Azure Database for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/tutorial-design-database-using-portal). I recommand that you could use Azure Database for MySQL to instead of ClearDB. How to do that we could refer to [migrate a Web App from ClearDB to Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/cleardb-migration-to-azure-database-for-mysql/).